# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer:

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, callback, artificial-intelligence

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
keras.layers.Dense(30, activation = "relu", input_shape=[8]),
keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = "relu"),
keras.layers.Dense(1)])

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3))

checkpoint_cb = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("Model-{epoch:02d}.h5")

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10,
             validation_data=(X_valid,y_valid),
               callbacks=[checkpoint_cb])
```

I am trying to fit a model using the callbacks but I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 8 but received input with shape [None, 28, 28]
```

What can be the possible error?

Answer (score 0):

The shape of your X_train is `(None,28,28`) but you are giving input of shape `(None,8)` to your dense layer.

Reshape your X_train

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 28*28)
```

Model should be

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
keras.layers.Dense(30, activation = "relu", input_shape=(784,)),
keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = "relu"),
keras.layers.Dense(1)])
```